# Mac OS X debug startup items to see what is causing slow startup

Tags: macos, mac, boot, debug

I have several menu bar applications loading on startup. 2 of them load immediately, but then there is a 10-20 second pause before the other 6 or 7 load.

I would like to know what is causing this halt. Is there any way I can review the order in which the applications are loading, so I know what the cause is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar delay, but it's closer to 30-60 seconds. It's probably caused by the software or drivers for my Huawei USB modem, because it's removed if I just unplug the USB modem before logging in.

You could check if there's anything interesting in Console. If disabling login items or disconnecting peripherals doesn't work, try disabling launchd services or kernel extensions. Just move them away from the LaunchAgents, LaunchDaemons, or Extensions folders. You can use [Consultant's Canary](http://khiltd.com/software/consultants_canary) to print a list of components that didn't come with OS X.

Comment: +1 for Consultant's Canary. I haven't tried it yet, but it looks ... useful.